# javascript + mysql live changes

Tags: javascript, mysql, socket.io

I read several tutorials, but I couldn't find a working example for my case.

I want to have a live-refresh (side-wise), whenever there is a change on the database (lets say I'd change values via phpmyadmin).

From what I understood, [socket.io](http://socket.io/) should be one solution. Also, I found [this tutorial here](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/), but it seems outdated, so it doesn't work anymore (from what I can tell).

Are there any alternatives or working examples? It can be pretty basic, but using `setInterval` with a param in range of 100 - 500 seems a bit to heavy, right? I can't wait for more than 1 sec.

I'm not sure, if there are any listeners or service, which can "push" a change to a JS-site, so I wouldn't rely on the JavaScript timeout-function.

Also, from the docs (and examples) on socket.io, I found ways to run the server on localhost, but not on the server. Lets say, I have this:

```
var.app = require('http').createServer(handler),
...
app.listen(8000);
```

it seems to listen to `localhost:8000`. Can I just replace this param to a live-url?

Comment: I don't think you can replace it with a live-url since socket.io is "listening" to a port number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets, it's already widely supported, but you still need to have a WebSockets server running on your machine, you still would NOT be able to actually send changes that you have made in phpmyadmin, because PHP does not know if you made any changes there.

The solution would be really complicated probably, because you would have to combine options, most of the stuff you could probably solve with WebSockets, so you would just send notifications from PHP to JavaScript, but apart from that, you would also have to check the database for changes, if you really wanted to monitor changes by you in phpmyadmin ( which I strongly advise against, it is easier, to create functions that modify the database in a way that you want, then to check the database every some ms ).

Your structure would probably look something like:

JavaScript -> connects to -> PHP WebSockets server

and on every change you submit the change to JavaScript.

Sorry, I cannot help you on setting the WebSockets server, but I know that Symfony2 has a package for it, you could go download and reverse-engineer it.

Here's the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API